# "Forwarding" a USB device's signal through a pair of USB ports on a PC

Tags: usb

My goal is to plug an Xbox One controller into my PC through a USB port, then run a USB cable from my PC to my Xbox One, in such a way that the controller is recognized and usable by both the PC and the Xbox One at the same time.

My searches for both software and hardware solutions came up empty.

A software solution would be ideal, but is this even possible? I'm prepared to start toying around with PyUSB if necessary, but I'm hoping I missed an easier answer somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that - In general USB hosts and devices are VERY distinct, and you're essentially trying to have your controller talk to two devices as once. You'd probably need some custom hardware masqurading as a controller talking to one device based on the input on the other, but that's probably out of SU's scope